# "suffix or operands invalid for 'shr'"

Tags: assembly, bit-shift, att

I'm trying to get rid of the lower bits (before doing a `popcnt`) in a register, but can't seem to get the syntax for the instruction right. I want to clear the lower `%rdx` bits from the value in `%r8d`. Searching told me the count argument should be an 8-bit register, so I'm currently at:

```
shrl %dl, %r8d
```

GAS complains about this, and I've really no clue what exactly the arguments should be if those are wrong.

Comment: Without BMI2, variable shifts on GPRs are only by `cl`. Haswell will have BMI2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According intel PRM, you should use `%cl` instead of `%dl`

Comment: ...well that's unintuitive, guess I shouldn't just skim that manual. Thanks.